# C# create JSON for REST Api call

Tags: c#, json, rest, api, jira

I am trying to create an issue in Jira with a POST in C#. 
The call returns this JSON:

```
{
   "fields": {
      "project":
      {
         "key": "BBR"
      },
      "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
      "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
      "issuetype": {
         "name": "Story"
      }
  }
}
```

I want to implement a method in C#, so I created the class JiraCreateIssueResponse:

```
{
        public List<string> Project { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<string> IssueType { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    }
```

and below I have the method where I tried to make the concrete call using the parameters given:

```
JiraCreateIssueResponse JiraIssueParams = new JiraCreateIssueResponse
            {
                Project = { $"key = {ProjectKey}" },
                Summary = summary,
                Description = "",
                IssueType = { $"name = Story" }
            };

            RestRequest restRequest = GetRestRequest(Method.POST, $"{JiraConstants.Urls.Issue}", JiraIssueParams, null);
```

However, I implemented a test which verifies this method and it gives me an error about deserialization, so I concluded that I did not parse well my JSON. 
Does anyone have any idea about my mistake ?
I tried other ways of implementing the JSON and using the values, but I had the same issue.

Comment: `{      "issuetype": {
         "name": "Story"
      }}` does issuetype(or project) looks like a list/array for you? it is an object(or dictionary)

Comment: and how should I implement this ?

Comment: You'll need to modify your class `..., Project = new Project { Key = "BBR" }, IssueType = new IssueType { Name = "Story" }`. Then how does `GetRestRequest()` serialize and send your `JiraIssueParams`?

Answer (score 0):

Your class should look like this:

```
public class JiraResponse
{
    public class JiraResponseProject
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
    }

    public class JiraResponseIssueType
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    private JiraResponseProject _project = new JiraResponseProject();
    private JiraResponseIssueType _issueType = new JiraResponseIssueType();

    public JiraResponseProject Project => _project;
    public JiraResponseIssueType IssueType => _issueType;

    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment and we are using Jira as well and utilize the API, there is an existing wrapper around the API for c# here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Atlassian.SDK/ this will save you bunch of work - definetly did for me.

Project site is hosted: [on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/wiki/Home)